# Display Opencv image send by event to Qt GUI

Tags: multithreading, qt, opencv, c++11

I am trying for days now to find a proper solution to the following problem(stated below), and I have no more ideas now. Therefore, I need help from more experienced devs:

I have a class independant from QT (and I want it to stay like this) that generate openCV images in a secundary thread. Then it raise an event which pass the images.

```
    while (1)
        {
            if (timerActived & this->_camReady)
            {
                vector<Mat>* images = new vector<Mat>;
                images = this->AcquireImg();
                __raise this->frameAcquired(images);
            }
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(_frameTimeLaps));
        }
```

This event is hooked by my MainWindow and a method is supposed to display my images on my GUI.

```
    void MainWindow::displayFrame(vector<Mat>* frames) {
        vector<Mat>* frames2 = new vector<Mat>();
        frames2 = frames;
        for (int i = 0; i < frames2->size(); ++i) {
            this->camFrames->at(i)->showImage(frames2->at(i));
        }
    }
```

During the runTime, when the Main Thread access the images I get the following error :

ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread.

I understand that I am not using threads properly, but I have no idea how to create an asynchronous event now.

Thank you for help,
Valentin

### EDIT 1 :

It seems to me that the real question is : can I use normal std::thread and native event to communicate with the main Qthread ?

Comment: Is your OpenCV thread wrapped in a QThread subclass?

Comment: If the receiving object is on a different thread you need to [post](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) the event.  Note also that it's your responsibility to ensure that access to any data associated with the `QEvent` is accomplished in a thread safe manner.

Comment: Thanks for help. No my OpenCV thread isn't wrapped in a QThread class, because Qt is not included in the class where the thread is created. (I want to make my controller independant from Qt if it is possible).
So I am trying to use native C++11 event to reach the main thread, and I guess I can't post the event with postEvent for the same raison above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to solve the problem, after all.

The idea is to give the main thread access to the Mat coming from the second thread. So I modified my function displayFrame like this :

```
    void MainWindow::displayFrame(vector<Mat>* frames) {

        //QThread::
        QThread* this_thread = QThread::currentThread();
        FrameWrapper* worker = new FrameWrapper();

        worker->moveToThread(this_thread);

        QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(frameSent(vector<Mat>*)), this, SLOT(showImg(vector<Mat>*)));

        emit worker->frameSent(frames);
        //this->camFrames->at(0)->showImage(frame);
    }
```

The new function showImg is doing the job of the old displayFrame. The signal/slot process permit to access image from the GUI Thread as wanted.